# django unittesting user login appears to be unauthorized

Tags: django

I've written 3 tests written based on documentations that I've read to see what's the best way to unittest a user login page.
They all have the same purpose just for learning purposes.
All are failing and I would like to find out why and fix them.

The login page redirects to the root page which would show a table if the user is authenticated.

**test_login1**: returns a 200 but the page content indicates that login failed which comes from {% if form.errors %} of the loging.html

**test_login2**: returns a 200 but the page content displays an empty table indicating that request.user.is_authenticated must have been false

**test_login3**: returns a 302 and fails

my tests.py

```
class MyPage(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@hotmail.com', password='top_secret')

    def test_login1(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), {'username': 'mark', 'password': 'mark'}, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert not "Failed to login" in response.content, "Failed to login!"

    def test_login2(self):
        request = self.factory.get(reverse('login'))
        request.user = self.user
        response = views.index(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert "Pie" in response.content, "User is not authenticated!"

class AccountTests(APITestCase):
    def test_login3(self):
        self.client.login(username='jaconb', password='top_secret')
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert "Pie" in response.content, "Missing content. Actual content: %s" % response.content
        self.client.logout()
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from bookstore.models import Book

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect 

@login_required
def index(request):
    entries = Book.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Failed to login.</p>
    {% endif %}


    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
       </table>

       <input type="submit" value="login" />
       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

**update**

I made some corrections and also instead of showing the data in the index page, moved it to a mybooks.html page but I'm still facing the same problem:

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/mybooks'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'bookstore.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'bookstore.views.index'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
        'template_name': 'login.html', 'redirect_field_name': '/mybooks'
       }, name='login'),
    url(r'^mybooks/$', 'bookstore.views.mybooks'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())


@login_required
def mybooks(request):
    entries = Book.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('mybooks.html', locals())
```

tests.py:

```
class MyPage(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@hotmail.com', password='top_secret')

    def test_login1(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), {'username': self.user.username, 'password': self.user.password}, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert not "Failed to login" in response.content, "Failed to login!"

    def test_login2(self):
        request = self.factory.post(reverse('login'))
        request.user = self.user
        response = views.mybooks(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert "Pie" in response.content, "Missing content. Actual content: %s" % response.content

class AccountTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@hotmail.com', password='top_secret')


    def test_login3(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)
        response = self.client.get('/mybooks', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert "Pie" in response.content, "Missing content. Actual content: %s" % response.content
        self.client.logout()
```

mybooks.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Failed to login.</p>
    {% endif %}
      <div align="right"><a href="/">home</a></div>
      <br/>

      <table border="1">
      <tr><td><strong>Title</strong></td><td><strong>Author</strong></td><td><strong>Description</strong></td></tr></strong>
      {% for book in entries %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
          <td>{{ book.description }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**test_login1**: You are trying to login with a non existent user, create the user first (or just use the self.user credentials!):

```
    def test_login1(self):
            User.objects.create_user(
                username='mark',
                email='mark@something.xy',
                password='mark'
                )
        response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), {'username': 'mark', 'password': 'mark'}, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert not "Failed to login" in response.content, "Failed to login!"
```

**test_login2**: Your login form uses POST method not GET! try this:

```
request = self.factory.post(reverse('login'))
```

**test_login3**: Wrong username, notice `jaconb` instead of `jacob`.
Also this test is expecting a redirect, since it's testing for some content not present on the login page.
(notice the : `assert "Pie" in response.content`, where "Pie" is never present on the login page! you should probably check for the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in your `settings.py`)

I hope this helps!

---

To get "Pie" to display for authenticated users try this template tag:

`{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a>Pie</a>
{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks @HassenPy. I made the correction changing get to post. I also added LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to setting.py. As for the authentication, I just had forgotten to paste it...I'm still facing the main problem. Can you take a look at my update and perhaps you can catch more issues please? thanks

Comment: I guess the problem is that I need to test that after logging in, the use is redirected to mybooks.html and can see the word "Pie" that is only displayed if the user is authentic. I thought setting follow=true will take care of it.

Comment: Well, I fixed test_login1.     I should not use 'password': self.user.password, because self.user.password returns the hashed password. Instead, I just specified the password of the user that I created. I still need to figure out how to fix the other tests.

Comment: you should assert for 302 response status, since you are redirecting at every login.

Comment: I see; when using follow=True, I get 200 return code while when not using it, I get 302.

Comment: You can update your post with the solution and accept the answer if it helped you, its good practice in SO community :)

Comment: I would. The main problem remaining is that I want to ensure that the query content "Pie" is displayed for an authorized user and I still have not been able to get that working. That's why I've not finalize this yet.

Comment: I tried putting "Pie" in the if statement it works indicating that the user is authenticated. The word "Pie" was actually supposed to be in the entries  {% for book in entries %} which works fine when running the server but does not work in the unittest because unittest creates a separate db. Thanks HassenPy.